# Best means to store/add/delete a simple set of data in Java

Tags: java, properties

I'm looking to have certain data stored for more than the lifetime of the program. Basically it's going to be an ID number, and two other elements that follow each ID. There would less than 20 entries at all times, so the means of storing it/retrieving it would not have to be restrained by capacity/size issues.

I thought about XML but it seems to be a little more work than necessary for this small of a procedure. I also thought about just keeping the entries in a text file... I suppose the biggest issue would be what means to search for an item and delete an item.

I'm sure someone with more experience would have a better idea for what I should do. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: So is this data going to change over the execution of the app or is it static?

Comment: The actual data will not change, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned the data remains static so it can be considered as a config type data. I recommend using a properties file approach here using the [Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class.

You can check out the tutorials on how to utilize it [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) and also another one [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0434.html).

For your scenario, the key would be the `id` number and the values would be the 2 elements that corresponds to that `id` number.

Example of myApp.props file:

> id=values
>  1=a,b
>  2=c,d

Then you can retrieve the values this way:-

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(new FileInputStream("myApp.props"));
            if(properties.containsKey("1")){
                String[] propertyValues = properties.getProperty("1").split(","); //gets you a and b
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //handle it
        } finally{
            //handle it
        }
```

Comment: Got to agree this is one of the simplest ways to store the information

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in making the data store readable by a human, consider making your object serializable and simply serializing it into a file output stream.

You can even serialize lists of serialized objects.